# Video call on Unity with WebRTC without server

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc

I'd like to make a video call app using WebRTC on Unity. I have investigated almost of the WebRTC services and found out that the WebRTC services require "my own server" for authentication(to give users privileges to access the server). Some companies even say "no server needed" but I actually had to register my server domain to use their services - sounds weird...

my questions are :

1. why do we need to prepare server (It seems the service provider could have prepared auth servers as well)
2. Is there any WebRTC service as a complete sever bundle(really woking with client-side app only)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For webrtc you need at at least to exchange the candidate between the peer to allow them to connect (it's called signaling int the webrtc architechture), you also need server to handle network path if nat doesn't allow it (stun/turn server).

There is a lot of server and client depending on your use case complexity and stack. (kurento, Freeswitch, peerJs server ... )